# svg image not displaying on my website

Tags: .htaccess, svg, web-config, mime-types

I have a website: [My Website](http://garcestechnology.com/)

it is hosted on godaddy, it has an preload intro animation using .svg file and it is not showing, also the svg logo in my footer.

I already tried everything, like adding a .svg MIME type in my web.config, editing my .htaccess but wasn't able to solve it.

Do you have any suggestion on what might be the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your svg files are served with MIME-Type application/octet-stream, but should be served with image/svg+xml.
Try in your .htaccess "AddType image/svg+xml"

Comment: http://garcestechnology.com/wp-content/themes/gt2014/images/logo/classic.svg and the other SVG are still served with "Content-Type: application/octet-stream". So maybe you don't have the rights to define MimeTypes in your .htaccess

Comment: your right, I just called them, they said to switch the environment to linux.

Comment: Just had to fix this for someone: Try this instead of what's in the answer: 

AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
<NewLine>
AddEncoding gzip svgz

From: https://davidwalsh.name/serve-svg-image

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing "xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" as an attribute attribute of the root  element. Your svg tag should look START this:

Read more about it here:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#NewDocument